# Xcode 11b4: Directory not found for option .../lib/swift/undefined

Tags: xcode, compiler-warnings, mac-catalyst

When building my project for iOS only, everything's fine. When adding the **Mac** option, there is a strange warning:

`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/undefined'`

So, what is that `undefined` thing Xcode is looking for? And how to fix it? Or is it simply a bug in Xcode?

Comment: Getting tons of those here too... very likely it’s an Xcode bug and hopefully will be fixed in the next beta.